# How to properly setup a modal shop with FastSpring?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I am currently exploring [FastSpring](https://fastspring.com/), but their examples are very poorly documented so I struggle to understand even the most basic examples on how to create a modal dialog for my products. In the link below, they have an example for a "Buy The Photo.io App" but their respective JavaScript code fails on my test webpage.

https://fastspringexamples.com/full-cart/modal-carts/

In specific, in line #176:

```
var fsb_modal = document.getElementById('fsb-modal');
```

After copying parts over to my test webpage, this is where the script breaks. Were does `fsb-modal` come from? Where is this created? There is no explanation how the "JavaScript" code is embedded into the HTML. Any help is highly appreciated!

P.S. My test web-page includes the `script` directive from my test-account:

```
<script
    id="fsc-api"
    src="https://1234567890.cloudfront.net/sbl/0.8.3/fastspring-builder.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"
    data-storefront="x-y-z.test.onfastspring.com/popup-x-y-z">
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by where is `fsb-modal` coming from? It is part of HTML.

Comment: That's the point. It's not. Open the link, where is it?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. In the link you attached switch to HTML tab and see line 76.

Comment: What in the world... my chrome didn't find anything when I open the "Find in Page...". I would accept this as an answer

Comment: Sure will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` with id `fsb-modal` is part of HTML and describes content for shopping cart modal. On the [link](https://fastspringexamples.com/full-cart/modal-carts/) you mentioned, it is under HTML tab on line 76:

```
<!--
    This is the modal shopping cart.  The contents of the below will be populated by the handlebars script defined below.
-->
<div id="fsb-modal" class="fsb-modal">
    <div class="fsb-modal-content" id="fsb-modal-content">
        <div class="fsb-modal-header" style="background: #28a745; color: #ffffff;">
            <span id="fsb-close" class="fsb-close">&times;</span>
            <span class="fsb-cart_title">Shopping Cart</span>
        </div>
        <div class="fsb-modal-body">
            <div id="fsb_error" class="fsb-alert fsb-alert-danger" role="alert">
                <p class="fsb-alert-heading"><strong>I'm sorry, there was an issue.</strong></p>
                <p id="fsb_error_msg"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="fsb" data-fsc-selections-smartdisplay>
                <div data-fsc-selections-smartdisplay data-fsc-items-container='fastspring_shopping_cart' data-fsc-filter="selected=true" class="fsb-container-fluid px-5 py5">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-fsc-selections-smartdisplay-inverse>
                <p class="fsb-emptyCart">Your cart is empty.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```